# C++ how to call a parent class method from contained class?

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to make a call to a Parent class method from a contained object, but have no luck with the following code. What is the standard way to do it?

I have searched around and this seems to work for inherited objects, but not for contained objects. Is it right to call it a Parent class even? Or is it called an Owner class?

```
class Parent{
private:
  Child mychild;

public:
  void doSomething();
}

class Child{
public:
  void doOtherThing();
}

void Child::doOtherThing(){
  Parent::doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A contained object has no special access to the class that contains it, and in general does not know that it is contained. You need to pass a reference or a pointer to the containing class somehow - for example:

```
class Child{
public:
  void doOtherThing( Parent & p );
};

void Child::doOtherThing( Parent & p ){
   p.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The child has no connection to the parent class at all. You'll have to pass 'this' down to the child (probably in the constructors) to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If the child needs to interact with the parent, then it will need a reference to that object; at present, the child has no notion of an owner.